# Why JVM keeps running for ScheduledExecutorService when I am cancelling the task?

Tags: java

The code is :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture<?> hi = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(()-> hi.cancel(false), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("find me" + hi.get());
}
```

I wanted to know what ScheduledFuture.get() does. After running the code main thread dies because of exception but the JVM keeps running why so?

EDIT - Answer For for those who did not understood, The JVM Process exits if there are only daemon threads or other way to put it Java programs terminate when all non-daemon threads finish.
The threads which are created by ScheduledExecutorService are not daemon threads and thus the process does not exits.

Comment: Because you never [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: For for those who did not understood, The JVM Process exits if there are only daemon threads. The threads which are created by ScheduledExecutorService are not daemon threads and thus the process does not exits.